# Copy cells and paste them in all those that are empty

Tags: vba, excel

I need a macro that, (at it says in the title) copy the **two last cells**, in this case **A419** and **B419**, and paste their value until it find others that contain information.

In example:

As you can see in the image, there's the Value **1004-004** and **36300025** and a lot of empty cells below. And more below theres **1004-005** and **36300026** Something like from 420 to 434. And then select 1004-005 and 36300026 and repeat the process.

This:

[image: This]

To this:

[image: to this]

Well, that's all, i don't really know how to do it, so i'll be very grateful if you can help me out guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While you should be posting code you need help with, I already have this code written.  Just select your range and then run this macro.

```
 Sub Fill_from_above()

 For Each c In Selection.Cells  
     If c.Value = "" Then
         c.Value = c.Offset(-1, 0).Value  
     End If 
 Next c
 End Sub
```

Comment: Hello mooseman, i've tried your code and it've worked perfecty.
I'm so sorry for not posting my code, that's why i'm a little bit new at VBA and i don't know how to do that procedure.
Thanks for your quick answer! It's very appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

use a basic formula on the blank cells. convert the formula results to values if you wish.

```
with worksheets("sheet1")
    with intersect(.columns("a:b"), .usedrange)
        .specialcells(xlcelltypeblanks).formular1c1 = "=r[-1]c"
        .value = .value2
    end with
end with
```